# sed can't differentiate CR from LF if both exist in the same file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, tr

I have a file where CR (\r) and LF (\n) exists in the same file.

```
a1 a2 CRLF
b1 LF
b2 CRLF
c1 c2 CRLF
```

The file need to be fixed to:

```
a1 a2 CRLF
b1 b2 CRLF
c1 c2 CRLF
```

The logic is simple: remove LF that is not preceded by CR with empty string:

```
sed 's/[^\r]\n//g' input.txt > output.txt
```

However, this doesn't work!

I had to delete all the occurrences of LF, and replace all the remaining CR with CRLF  :

```
cat input.txt | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\r/\r\n/g' >output.txt
```

this bugs me. why isn't sed working??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Etan Reisner is basically correct - sed handles text as newline-delimited lines, so you need to jump through some hoops to make it deal with newlines directly.  Just because you can do this doesn't mean it's the cleanest way, but if you don't have other tools at your disposal, here's an example of how to do this:

```
sed -e 's/[^\r]$/&/' -e te -e b -e :e -e N -e 's/\n//'
```

What this command does is:

1. `s/[^\r]$/&/` - replace a CR at the end of a line with ... itself.
2. `te` - test and branch: if the previous substitution succeeded, branch to the indicated label.  (We needed it to succeed, which is why it substituted with itself)
3. `b` - unconditionally branch to the end of the script
4. `:e` - create a label for the earlier `te` command to jump to
5. `N` - append the next line into the pattern space.  This results in a pattern space with an embedded newline.
6. `s/\n//` - delete the embedded newline.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` doesn't see line endings in the line it is operating on.

This is the same reason that `sed 's/\n//'` doesn't give you a file with only one line.

The newlines are handled "internally".

This is the sort of task that `dos2unix`/`unix2dos`/etc. may handle for you more directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN { ORS = RS } { gsub(/\n/, ""); print }'
```

With the record separator `RS` set to `\r\n`, the file will be split into records separated by, well, `\r\n`, so removing newlines in those records removes all newlines that are not preceded by `\r`. Setting `ORS` (the output record separator) to `RS` makes it so that the output file still has CRLF line endings.

Note that multi-character `RS` is not strictly POSIX-conforming. The most common awks support it, though.

Or there's the Perl way:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n//'
```

This relies on a negative lookbehind; `(?<!\r)` matches an empty string that is not preceded by `\r`. Note that unlike sed, Perl without `-l` does not remove newlines from the input, so no special tricks are necessary to remove them.